# docker cp command adds giberish at the start of the file I copy

Tags: python, docker

I took a file from a stopped container using this command `docker container cp d672b9ffc8f5:/usr/src/geonode/geonode/settings.py - > settings.py`. I wanted to change a mistake I did and the container would not start. I noticed at the top that there were a lot of gibberish characters, I deleted them, changed what I wanted and pushed it back with this command `docker cp settings.py d672b9ffc8f5:/usr/src/geonode/geonode/`. I took a look at the file and found out that the gibberish characters were there stil.

```
settings.py01006440000000000000000000241720142436452730114770ustar0000000000000000#########################################################################
    #
    # Copyright (C) 2016 OSGeo
    #
    # This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    # it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    # the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    # (at your option) any later version.
    #
    # This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    # but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    # MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
    # GNU General Public License for more details.
    #
    # You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    # along with this program. If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
    #
    #########################################################################
```

So now the container doesn't start and I assume it's that python doesn't like the characters before the comments (#). Anybody has a clue?

Comment: why do you use `> settings.py` for this? Command may display some messages in console and you write all these values also to file. Did you see what you get when you skip `> settings.py`? As for you should use directly `settings.py` instead of `-`

Comment: If the output of [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) is `-`, it writes a tar file to stdout and not a bare file.  This seems to be a question about running a prebuilt application, though; do you have any source code you're having trouble with, or anything that would make this a more programming-oriented question?